# Find an equation of the sphere with center at $(2, 1, −1)$ and radius $4$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> Find an equation of the sphere with center at $(2, 1, −1)$ and radius $4$.  Find an equation for the intersection of this sphere with the y-z plane; describe this intersection geometrically.

To solve this I used the following equation:

$(4)^2=(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2$

The equation for the intersection with the y-z plane happens when $x=0$ so the equation becomes $(4)^2=(y-1)^2+(z+1)^2$, which can be described geometrically this way:

$\{\left(2,y,z : y,z \in \mathbb R\right)\}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Don't ignore the $(-2)^2$.

Comment: @HenryW where am I ignoring this?  Sorry I must have missed it (obviously)?!

Comment: When $x = 0$, the right side becomes $(0-2)^2 + (y-1)^2+(z+1)^2$

Comment: Ahhhhh!  You're right, thanks for catching that!

Comment: @HenryW so that changes $\{\left(2,y,z : y,z \in \mathbb R\right)\}$ to $\{\left(0,y,z : y,z \in \mathbb R\right)\}$, right?

Comment: Yes. Also you are supposed to describe it geometrically, so it would be a circle centred at $(0, 1, -1)$ with radius $\sqrt{12}$.